# Android Maps Custom Maker Search?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm looking to create a custom Google map, using a list of coordinates with an attached name to add markers. I know how to add a marker or two to a map, although I'm assuming there's a way to loop through them and add them to the map.

Is it possible to loop through a list of coordinates to be added to the map? Furthermore, is it possible to search through that list?

Answer (score 1):

you can loop trough every array / arrayList / other repository you have that contains objects that got `Latlng` coordinates and add them to the map like so:

```
    for (Task tempTask : tasksRepository)
    {
        LatLng latlng = new LatLng(tempTask.getLatitude(), tempTask.getLongtitude());                       
        newmarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title(tempTask.getTitle()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_for_map_blue)));  
    }
```

Searching this repository has nothing to do with the map. and could be done as in any other case.

Comment: And I'm assuming since it's an array/arrayList, it would allow me to implement what is essentially a search function? (loop through until it matches to something in the array etc)

Comment: yes as you would implement a regular search procedure, in a array/arraylist. this has nothing to do with the map. arraylist has some method that will be usefull to you in your search as indexOf and get: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html.
and please if you found my answer helpful and answered your question, accept it.